# how to get real path of root directory for glassfish using servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to create and put file on run time at server(say glassfish) root directory.

If I will get real path(C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot) of server root directory using servlet then I can easily create file on that location.

Any body, if know, please tell me!

Comment: What happens if your webapp is inside a WAR or EAR file and there is no filesystem?

Answer (score 5):

JSP:

```
String path = application.getRealPath("/");
```

Servlet:

```
String path = getServletContext.getRealPath("/");
```

Comment: request.getRealPath("/") returns C:\project\myproject\target\myapplication\  My requirement is not an application specific. I just want to get path of root directory of glassfish server which should be C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot.

Answer (score 3):

you can try following:

```
System.getProperty("catalina.base");
```

And you can find other properties by watching following variable in debug mode.

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
```